# Can't Install `Az` module in PowerShell 7.3.x

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-core, powershell-5.1

My Windows 11 laptop has two versions of PowerShell installed:

- 5.1.22621.963
- 7.3.1 (PowerShell Core)

Following [MS instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-9.3.0), I want to install the `Az` module in PowerShell 7.3, so I use this command:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

This gives me the following error:

> Install-Package: The following commands are already available on this
> system:'Login-AzAccount,Logout-AzAccount,Resolve-Error,Send-Feedback'. This module 'Az.Accounts' may override the
> existing commands. If you still want to install this module 'Az.Accounts', use -AllowClobber parameter

This error is discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206978/unable-to-install-az-powershell-module-with-ps7-on-windows10).  The solution given there is to remove all the pre-existing `Az` modules from the PowerShell 5.x installation.  This doesn't fit my situation, as (1) I don't have any `Az` modules currently installed in either version of PowerShell and (2) I'm not interested in modifying my PowerShell 5.x installation.  Please notice these results:

```
# From PowerShell 5.x
PS C:\Users\BArias> Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRM -AllVersions -OutVariable AzVersions

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
5.7.0      AzureRM                             https://www.power... Azure Resource Manager Module
```

And then...

```
# From PowerShell 7.3.x
PS C:\Users\BArias> Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRM -AllVersions -OutVariable AzVersions
Get-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AzureRM'.
```

I get the same "No match" result for `-Name Az`. In other words, there should be no reason that I need to remove either `Az` or `AzureRM` from my PowerShell 7.3.x, because such things simply aren't there. Furthermore, I am complying with the [MS "coexistence" rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-9.3.0#az-and-azurerm-coexistence) of `AzureRM` and `AZ`.

So this brings me back to square one.  Why am I getting the `This module 'Az.Accounts' may override the existing commands` error, when my PowerShell 7.3.x does not have `AzureRM` installed?

It seems like installing the `Az` module into PowerShell 7.3.x is a no-brainer, so why does it not "just work?"  I'm left with the impression that maybe there is something inherently incorrect with attempting to install the `Az` module into PowerShell 7? For example, is MS simply expecting that I will use the "Azure Cloud Shell" and I shouldn't be fiddling with my PowerShell 7?

Comment: Try `Get-Command Login-AzAccount | Select Name, Module` to see if command exists and if so, from what module.

Comment: @Daniel it says the module is `AzureRM.Profile`.  The heck? I'm not sure what to do with that information. When I then issue `Get-InstalledModule` and specify `-Name AzureRM.Profile`, it says "no match was found."  What the heck?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background information**:

- [`Get-InstalledModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Get-InstalledModule) does *not* list all locally *available* modules, it lists only those that were *installed with [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module)*, in a *given edition* of PowerShell.
- To see all locally available modules, use [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module) with the `-ListAvailable` switch (without `-ListAvailable`, only the *currently loaded* modules are listed.
- Modules *not* covered by `Get-InstalledModule` include:

  - Modules that *ship with PowerShell*.
  - Modules *manually copied* into one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, the environment variable that PowerShell uses for [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading).
  - In [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), specifically, those modules that *were* installed with `Install-Module`, but *from Windows PowerShell*, in the `AllUsers` scope (`-Scope AllUsers`), given that PowerShell (Core)'s `$env:PSModulePath` contains the following *Windows PowerShell*-specific directories *too*:

    - `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` (the dir. for the `AllUsers` scope of *user-installed* modules)
    - `$env:windir\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` (the modules that *ship with* Windows PowerShell)

---

Therefore, to be sure that there are truly no `Az`-related modules installed, run the following:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable Az* | Select-Object Name, Path
```

If you find any, uninstall them - possibly from *Windows PowerShell* - with [`Uninstall-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Uninstall-Module) (to uninstall modules in the `AllUsers` scope, you'll need to run *with elevation*), and then try installing from PowerShell (Core) again.

If you do *not* want to remove installed Azure modules from your *Windows PowerShell* installation, you can try the following (untested):

- Before running `Install-Module` in PowerShell (Core), (temporarily) remove the `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` entry from `$env:PSModulePath`, so that `Install-Module` cannot discover the existing `Az*` modules there, which you can do as follows (this only modifies the *process-specific* copy of the environment variable; the next session will again see the registry-defined value):

  ```
  $env:PSModulePath = ($env:PSModulePath -split ';' -ne "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules") -join ';'
  ```
- Once installed in a PowerShell (Core)-specific directory (whether in the `AllUsers` or `CurrentUser` scope), that installation should take precedence over the version in `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`, given that PowerShell (Core)-specific entries are listed *before* the Windows PowerShell-specific ones in `$env:PSModulePath`.

Another, less desirable option would be to uninstall the module from the `AllUsers` scope in Windows PowerShell and *re-install in the `CurrentUser` scope* (of potentially *multiple* users that need it). Given that PowerShell (Core) sees only the `AllUsers`-scoped modules installed with `Install-Module`, moving them to the `CurrentUser` scope effectively hides them from PowerShell (Core).

Comment: Wow! This is an incredible answer.  For a bit more clarification...I think you are revealing that modules installed in Windows PowerShell are often (automatically?) pair-wise deployed into PowerShell Core.  If so, then to uninstall from the latter, I would "normally" uninstall from the former?  This would be a very strange circumstance, since the MS documentation I referenced in my OP makes it very clear that `AzureRM` and `Az` can co-exist, and no mention is made of needing to use either of your proposed solutions.  It's possible there is a third option we're missing?

Comment: @BrentArias, they're not _deployed_, they are just _visible_ to PowerShell Core, by virtue of including the two WinPS-directories listed in the answer in `$env:PSModulePath`. If PS Core sees your Azure module via `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`, i.e. the _WinPS_ all-users location and that is what prevents installing (a different) module in PS Core, then you'll either have to uninstall _from WinPS_ (or conceivably install in the _user_ scope instead) or try the proposed temporary-`$env:PSModulePath`-modification workaround. All of this isn't specific to Azure modules.

Comment: @BrentArias, I'm not familiar with the Azure modules, but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-9.3.0#az-and-azurerm-coexistence) state: 
"We do not support having both the AzureRM and Az PowerShell modules installed in Windows PowerShell 5.1 at the same time." It sounds like there's an explicit check, which also affects your cross-edition scenario.

Comment: My preference is first...attempt to change the Windows PowerShell `AzureRM` module from "all-users" to "user-scope".  I don't know how to do that, short of completely uninstalling and re-installing. Is there a better way? Otherwise, how exactly should `AzureRM` be completely re-installed, if necessary?  My second preference is your "temporary" path workaround, on condition that there is a way to revert to "as before" if I run into a problem - or otherwise do surgery on the path-config.  That means I want to know where (in the Registry?) this path info is kept, if I need heavy-handed repairs.

Comment: @BrentArias, modifying an `$env:` variable as shown in the answer only modifies the _process-local copy_ of it - the _persistent_ value that is stored in the registry automatically resurfaces if you start a new session. As for uninstalling and reinstalling: links to the relevant cmdlets, `Uninstall-Module` and `Install-Module`, are in the answer; use `-Scope CurrentUser`.